# Executing edits in parallel rather than sequentially

Tags: sed, edit

I want to apply a large number of edits to a file in parallel. That is I don't want the subsequent edit commands to modify already modified lines as they would if they pass through a sed pattern space.

Any tips?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the sed man page? Have you thought about using something like `awk` or perl/python/ruby/etc. instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/fred/wilma/g;t;s/wilma/betty/g' file
```

Use the fact that a substitution has taken place as a way of preventing further substitutions on that line. The `t` command will bail out if a substitution has succeeded.